# What is Colour-Colour-Intensity Diagram?

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics

What are [color-color intensity diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=colour-colour-intensity+diagram&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22color-color+intensity+diagram%22)? 
These are 3D plots usually used in high energy astrophysics ( particularly in relation to XRBs).

Comment: Have you seen [this CFA page](http://hea-www.cfa.harvard.edu/~craiga/CCIDiagrams.html) on CCI diagrams?

Comment: I have. But, I am looking for something which is much more verbose.